# Automated testing TFS/xUnit with ClassData only uses first assert

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a container class :

```
public class MyContainer : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var returns = new List<string>
        {
            "zero",
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "four"
        };
        foreach(var val in returns)
        {
            yield return new object[] {new MyClass{Value = val}};
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I created a simple test class, with just a value in it :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a unit test, like this :

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(MyContainer))]
public void T(MyClass v)
{
    Assert.Equal("one", v.Value);
}
```

I then associated the test with a test case in TFS. If I run the test, asserting for "one", the test in TFS fails, as expected, and the logs shows that all but one test fails.

When I change the assert to test for "zero", (ie, the first in the iterations), the test passes, even though the release log shows clear failures for each of the "non-zero" lists. The trx file also shows this, with a failed result, but the test shows succes, and finally in the log it shows me this :

```
2019-04-09T12:02:02.6247328Z Total Tests : 1, Passed Tests : 1
```

From what I understand, it would appear that TFS/xUnit only tests the first assert, if this is a success, the test is considered a success, regardless of the rest of the tests.

Have I missed something, or has anyone else encountered this problem?